# Entry renderer has color overflow

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Have custom entry, with custom entry renderer for Android:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

        if (!(e?.NewElement is MyEntry element))
        {
            return;
        }

        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        float cornerRdaius = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.CornerRadius, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        drawable.SetCornerRadius(cornerRdaius);
        drawable.SetColor(element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
        int stroke = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.BorderWidth, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        drawable.SetStroke(stroke, element.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
        int paddingLeft = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.Padding.Left, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        int paddingTop = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.Padding.Top, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        int paddingRight = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.Padding.Right, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        int paddingBottom = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.Padding.Bottom, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        Control.Background = drawable;
        Control.SetPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
    }
```

Result:
[image]

I'm trying to have the round corner be the outline of the control,

but somehow the background color flows outside the stroke,

Making it a rectangle.

How do I get the corners to clip the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to fix the overflow after many attempts, by overriding

UpdateBackgroundColor on the renderer:

```
protected override void UpdateBackgroundColor()
    {
        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        GradientDrawable drawable = Control.Background as GradientDrawable;
        if (drawable == null || !(Element is MyEntry element))
        {
            return;
        }
        drawable.SetColor(element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
    }
```

I guess that the Base behvior is adding/capturing another layer beind somehow and then colors it.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the effect with `Shape` in android.

create a **shape_roundcorner.xml** in `Resources/drawable` in android project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

   <solid android:color="#f00" />


   <stroke
     android:width="3dp"
     android:color="#000"
   />

   <corners
    android:radius="10dp"
    />
 </shape>
```

then in your entryrenderer:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
 {
     base.OnElementChanged(e);
     Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shape_roundcorner);
 }
```

the effect like below:

[image]

**Update**:

if you want to do it dynamically like:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        //Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shape);
        GradientDrawable mGroupDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        mGroupDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        mGroupDrawable.SetStroke(8, Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.stroke_color));//the value 8 and color you could define a bindableproperty in your custom entry.
        mGroupDrawable.SetColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.border_color));//the color you could define a bindableproperty in your custom entry.
        mGroupDrawable.SetCornerRadius(20);//the value 20 you could define a bindableproperty in your custom entry.
        Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(mGroupDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is actually where I started off from. I wanted to change to GradientDrawable as to support both stroke, CornerRadius and background colors, and to be able to change them dynamically in the renderer. The shape Xml seemed too stiff to me.

Comment: @o_w Your thought above seems to be correct, please check my update, but I did not reproduce your issue.Or you could try to set the shape.xml first,then call `GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)Control.Background;` and change the color and cornerRadius .

Comment: So, this is what I do now, cause I have MyEntry with BindableProperties for BorderWidth, BorderColor and CornerRadius, but I guess you couldn't recreate my issue. My renderer inherits from EntryRenderer, maybe this will help recreate it?

Comment: @o_w My renderer  inherits from EntryRenderer too,did you try to use shape.xml first,then change its color and cornerradius ?Maybe you could show the complete code.

Comment: I don't know how to change stroke on ShapeDrawable, so when I looked online I saw most solutions for Entry renderer go the GradientDrawable way. This is all the code there is in my custom renderer.

Comment: @o_w you could use `Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shape_roundcorner);` first,to see if it display correctly,if yes,then  use `GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)Control.Background;` to get the backgraound drawable and `drawable.SetStroke` ,`drawable.SetColor` and so on to change the attrbute